# Checking Android FAB visibility always returns VISIBLE from Robolectric test case

Tags: android, robolectric

While writing a Robolectric unit test, I noticed my `getVisibility()` call returned 0 (VISIBLE) after calling `fab.hide()`, so I assumed it was due to animation and to test it out, added a delayed check. Surprisingly it has also returned VISIBLE. On the actual device it works as expected and returns the correct values.

EDIT: just to clarify I'm using the FAB from the design support library.

My test code is really simple:

```
        fab.performClick();
        ShadowLooper.runUiThreadTasksIncludingDelayedTasks();
        assertThat(fab.isShown()).isFalse();
```

Code under test:

```
        mActionBunnot.hide();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                boolean shown = mActionBunnot.isShown();
                Log.d(TAG,""+shown);
            }
        },2000);
```

When run through Robolectric, both here and in the test, `isShown` returns `true`

Comment: If you comment your handler, will you get `isShown()` false in test?

Comment: No it's always true..

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: I have a test with code equivalent to `fab.performClick(); assertThat(fab.isShown()).isFalse();` And that was working just fine when I was using support library 26.1.0, but after I upgraded to version 27.1.1 `isShown` started to return true all the time so my test started failing. I have not figured out how to fix it though :(

Answer (score 2):

You can also **.isShown()** method to get the visibility.

Comment: Hmm, i'm still getting true from this... Will update my question with a few more details

Answer (score 2):

I know it is a bit late, but maybe useful for other people.
Robolectric executes all operations on one single thread. In the past this happened synchronously. Since version 4.3 Robolectric has the Looper PAUSED mode, which improves this behaviour as described in this blog: http://robolectric.org/blog/2019/06/04/paused-looper/